# Prevent a page loading after click for a specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a jQuery dialog box for a specific period of time before the clicked link begins loading the page but I'm having an issue with the duration. It doesn't seem to last as I expected. How can I fix? Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
               autoOpen: false,  
            });
            $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }, 10000);
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
        });
```

```css
#dialog {
        display: none;
    }
    
img {
        width: 300px;
        height: 250px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src=""></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <div class="images">
        <a href="https://www.site1.com">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.site2.com">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not put `e.preventDefault()` inside timeout, you need it right after click so that browser does not navigate away. And inside your timeout set the redirection click:

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
});

$(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = $(this).prop("href")
  }, 3000);
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="images">
  <a href="https://www.site1.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
  </a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.site2.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @JustMe I see no reason whatsoever why would my changes reflect on issue you are having, one shouldn't have anything to do with another. Also, remove all this from function, there is no need for that at all, I updated the snippet. Also make sure you are putting this script at right place. At bottom of body or wrap it all in `document ready`.

Comment: Everything is fine now, working as expected. Thanks a lot again!